# VB6: Getting image size in pixels

Tags: vb6

I put a picture box on a form and loaded some picture on it:

```
View1.Picture = LoadPicture(App.Path & "\sample2.bmp")
```

When I tried to get the width and height of the Picture property, the values I received are not in pixels nor twips. Does anybody knows how to determine the size of an image in pixels in Visual Basic 6?

Comment: What was the size measured in, then? You could probably make a very easy conversion..

Answer (score 8, accepted):

They are in [himetrics](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Himetric).

Use

```
With View1
  MsgBox .ScaleX(.Picture.Width, vbHimetric, vbPixels)
  MsgBox .ScaleY(.Picture.Height, vbHimetric, vbPixels)
End With
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! This is just what I asked for! Is there way to do it for an image stored in a StdPicture variable?

Comment: @ezpresso: Use `.ScaleX`/`.ScaleY` methods of a displayable object, such as `Form` or `PictureBox`. It's irrelevant that the picture doesn't come from the object you scale it to. See, himetrics are independed from screen resolution; when you convert them to pixels that are screen-dependant, you must use an object that can be displayed with these screen-dependant parameters.

Comment: Thank you! I am just wondering why are all that complications?! Why couldn't Microsoft just give us option to use pixels?!

Comment: @ezpresso: I can guess that it is better to have actual, true dimensions of a picture that don't depend on the various types of displays it can be displayed on. Pixels come in different sizes and even shapes.

Comment: Or you could use WIA 2.0 instead of the old stuff intrinsic to VB6.